# How to cleanup records that haven't changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image: dataset]

I'm wanting to cleanup my dataset. The left side would be what the raw data would look like. It's temperature readings based on time. I'm basically wanting to delete the row if the row above it has the same Temperature

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.  Also, try to explain the logic for your output.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want changes, use the ANSI standard `lag()` function, supported by most databases:

```
select zone, temperature, time
from (select t.*,
             lag(temperature) over (partition by zone order by time) as prev_temperature
      from t
     ) t
where prev_temperature is null or prev_temperature <> temperature;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead` to get the next row's values and delete the rows when the next row's value is the same.

```
with cte as (select t.*
             ,lead(temperature) over(partition by zone order by time) as next_temp
             from tbl t
            )
delete from cte
where next_temp is not null and next_temp=temperature
```